# Python での import 時は元ファイルの内容がそのまま実行される？

Tags: python3, import

Python 3 環境において、同じフォルダ内で別ファイルの関数を使おうと思いimportした際に `import` したファイルの処理が行われました。
（`print`文による表示が`import`先のファイルで一番最初に行われました）

関数だけを取り出したいのですが、`import`すると元ファイルそのまま実行されるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

はい。
importすると元ファイルがそのまま実行されます。

import時には実行せず関数だけを取り出したい場合は、import対象の.pyファイルで関数に囲まれていない処理を`if __name__ == "__main__":`の下に記述するよう書き換えてください。

参考資料:
[10分で分かるPythonのimport](https://qiita.com/kz23szk/items/5614fc3f05f0f7cf61ef)

Comment: ありがとうございます！