# [flask]ボタンでpython実行したい

Tags: python, flask

python初心者です。教えてください。
タイトル通り、ボタン押下でpython実行を行いたいのですが
ボタンを押下する前に実行されてしまいます。
ボタン押下後に実行させるには何が足りないのでしょうか。

index.html:

```
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="/test_client">
    <button type="submit">Start</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import test_client

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') 

@app.route('/test_client')
def get():
    return test_client.text_strings()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: `test_client.py`の中に、関数の外側かつ`if name == "__main__"`のインデントで囲まれていないコードはありませんか？参考:[Python での import 時は元ファイルの内容がそのまま実行される？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/89425)

Comment: payaneco様
ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りでした。
また、参考URLについても大変勉強になりました。